# Apps Registry error Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, django-1.8

Python version : 2.7.10 
Django version : 1.8
Environment : Virtual environment

Problem: Whenever i tried to run ./manage.py runserver or shell I get this error

```
"The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the "
 django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: The translation infrastructure 
 cannot be initialized before the apps registry is ready. Check that you 
 don't make non-lazy gettext calls at import time."
```

Based on some responses on some related posts, I have also checked my wsgi file and it has the updated way of referencing the wsgi application. Here's how my wsgi file looks:

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "instant_reports.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Any help/guidance on resolving this ?

Comment: So, it's telling you that you have calls to `gettext` that are being executed at import time. Can you show them?

Comment: I'm actually calling this at multiple places - is there any specific file I need to look at ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you use  `ugettext()` in your code? Change it to `ugettext_lazy().`Quoting [Django official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/applications/#troubleshooting):

> AppRegistryNotReady: This happens when importing an application configuration or a models module triggers code that depends on the app registry.
>
> For example, ugettext() uses the app registry to look up translation
>   catalogs in applications. To translate at import time, you need
>   ugettext_lazy() instead. (Using ugettext() would be a bug, because the
>   translation would happen at import time, rather than at each request
>   depending on the active language.)

Comment: No i'm using ugettext_lazy() across the board. Here's the snippet of how it's being imported "from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [lazy translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#lazy-translation) in your `settings.py` and any file (`views.py`, `models.py`) that might get imported while Django is boostrapped.

Comment: Yes. I already import them in those files using 

 "from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _" but still getting this error